# How can we set constraints programatically for dynamically added view on UITableViewCell

Tags: autolayout, ios-autolayout

I want to add constraints during the run time between the dynamically added view.

I have set the constraints but still m getting problems for message label which displays height more then required height.
Attached screen please check.
[image]

Here i want label height according to its text.

i have set auto-layout constraints between message label and this image attachment collectionView.
UILabel has height constraints of greater then or equal heights same constraints on image attachment collectionview.

Please help if you got proper understanding.

Comment: You have to use "addConstraint:" api for the same. Example below 

[cell.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:customImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:25.0]];

Apply your logic wisely

Comment: Thanks @DeepakPillai Actually the above screenshot includes this addConstraint api on dynamically added images but the problem is the message label height. Height automatically increased as label text length increase but the height of label is not according to the label text. Height is higher then normally it should be.